# What happens when the Paranormal Investigator looks at a Doppelganger or Copy Cat who is now bad?

Tags: one-night-werewolf

When a Doppelganger (or Copy Cat from the Vampires expansion) look at a role, their card now takes on the role they looked at. So, if they are swapped by a troublemaker, for example, the person who ends up with the Doppelganger card is the role the Doppelganger looked at.

Further, the Paranormal Investigator becomes any non-Villager role they look at and must then stop looking at cards.

In neither case are cards swapped.

My question is, what happens when the Paranormal Investigator looks at a Doppelganger who has looked at a card on the Werewolf (or Vampire) team?

First, if the Doppelganger is the first card they look at, do they assume that the Doppelganger is a Villager role and then look at a second card? I assume so. That's the only thing that seems fair.

Second, does the Paranormal Investigator become the non Villager role that the Doppelganger looked at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Daybreak rules state the following for the P.I. (emphasis added):

> If the P.I. sees the Doppelgänger that saw a Werewolf, he continues looking (he doesn't know what the Doppelgänger saw, and **does not become what the Doppelgänger saw**, even if the Doppelgänger saw a Werewolf or Tanner).
>
> *The Paranormal Investigator **is on the village team**, unless he finds a Werewolf, or if he finds a Tanner, in which case he becomes a Tanner and only wins if he dies.*

So a P.I. who sees a Doppelgänger stays on the Village team, regardless of what happens to the Doppelgänger.

Comment: I asked the game's makers before there was an answer, they got back to me:
We just checked out the link and the answer provided is correct.

Thank you, 
Bezier Games, Inc.

Comment: And presumably this sets the precedent for the later Copy Cat role.

Comment: I believe it does.